# How to UploadTask and Download a file

Tags: swift

Iam using an api call to upload a docx file and it will convert to pdf file. So My question is how to upload docx file like with uploadTask but how to get the file in response or how can i download(download task) after uploading.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading files via API, you need to covert it into data and then send it in POST body of the post API

For downloading files, in GET API, you will get the file in binary or base64 String, you will have to convert that base64 string into formatted file like PDF, DOCX, or txt and save it in iPhone memory.

Hope this will help you to download file: http://sketchytech.blogspot.in/2016/02/swift-download-file-using-nsurlsession.html.

Thanks

Comment: yes, but i am having an api where i can upload docx a file and it converts and returns a pdf file. In this i want both upload task and download task at a time.